# Adding cell to Table view when button tapped in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, view

i have to views in my app. mainMeasurements and historyMode. in main measurement, user can take photo and measure distance, speed and time. I need that app will save that measured datas in TableView in a historyMode, when reset button tapped (like a recents in a phone app). i already prepared datas and commented them. it should add cells to table view with image and "lastTop..." datas and show old ones too

```
class mainMeasurements: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate {

var speedArray: [String] = []
var arrayOfImages: [UIImage] = []
var distanceArray: [Int] = []

var lastTopDistance: String?
var lastTopSpeed: String?
var lastTopTime: String?

@IBOutlet weak var takePhoto: UIButton!   
@IBOutlet weak var mountainImage: UIImageView!     
@IBOutlet weak var speedLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var distanceLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var timerLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var resetButtonLabel: UIButton!

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "switchToHistory"{
//            let historyModeVc = segue.destination as! historyMode
//            historyModeVc.memoryPhoto = arrayOfImages.last
//            historyModeVc.historySpeedLabelMM = lastTopSpeed
//            historyModeVc.historyDistanceLabelMM = lastTopDistance
//            historyModeVc.historyTimerLabelMM = lastTopTime
        }
    }

@IBAction func resetDidTouch(_ sender: UIButton) {
        arrayOfImages.append(mountainImage.image!)

        self.lastTopSpeed = self.maxSpeed
        self.lastTopDistance = self.distanceLabel.text
        self.lastTopTime = self.timerLabel.text
        self.arrayOfImages.append(self.mountainImage.image!)
        
    }
 }
```

AND

```
import UIKit

class historyMode: UIViewController {
    
    var memoryPhoto: UIImage?
    var historyTimerLabelMM: String?
    var historySpeedLabelMM: String?
    var historyDistanceLabelMM: String?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
//        historyDistanceLabel.text = historyDistanceLabelMM
//        historySpeedLabel.text = historySpeedLabelMM
//        historyTimerLabel.text = historyTimerLabelMM
//        historyImage.image = memoryPhoto
        
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add new element to your dataSource and use `NotificationCentre` to call         `tableView.reloadData()` in `historyMode`

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken, you're inquiring about how to display your data on a table view?

You can parse your data like this and pass it to `historyMode`:

```swift
struct YourData {
    var arrayOfImages: [UIImage]
    var lastTopDistance: String?
    var lastTopSpeed: String?
    var lastTopTime: String?
}
```

Create a custom cell:

```swift
class CustomCell: UITableViewCell {
    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        
        // configure your cell UI
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    func set(with data: YourData) {
        // initialize your properties with the data you provide
    }
}
```

Register your custom cell with `historyMode` and pass your data to the custom cell:

```swift
var yourDataArray: [YourData]!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tableView.register(CustomCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "CustomCell")
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CustomCell", for: indexPath) as! CustomCell
    let yourData = yourDataArray[indexPath.row]
    cell.set(with: yourData)
    return cell
}
```

Comment: How to add cell to table view when button tapped?